# Why are the arms of the LIGO interferometer so long?

Tags: gravity, interferometry, ligo

The [LIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIGO) experiment consists of two interferometers, where each one of them has two 4 km long arms.

Within these, light is further trapped via Fabry-Pérot cavities to achieve a total path length of about 1,600 km.

Why does the path have to be so long? Isn't the phase that governs the interference pattern constant throughout the arm, since it just depends on the path difference between the two arms? Making them both long surely should not change this...?

Comment: The path difference does depend on the length. We're measuring the stretching of the earth. Assume the earth stretches uniformly 1%... say you measure a 100cm segment of land on the earth. It will stretch 1cm. Whereas a 100m object will stretch a total of 1m. 1m is much better to measure than 1cm. The measurement will be more accurate. And remember when we scale up the measurement to the length of the earth, the error scales up as well.

Comment: But that's the point - should it stretch uniformly? I though a gravitational wave, like any other wave, has an amplitude that controls the absolute displacement of the test mass?

Comment: I think a gravitational wave works differently. I'm not very knowledgeable in general relativity. But here's a nice animation that illustrates the idea: http://www.einstein-online.info/spotlights/gw_waves

Comment: *"like any other wave, has an amplitude that controls the absolute displacement of the test mass?"*  - gravitational waves are propagating disturbances in the spacetime metric.  If one were to, e.g., 'stretch' the metric by 1%, the distance between two objects increases by 1% so, the greater the initial separation, the greater the change in separation.

Comment: but how does trapping light in F-P cavities help here?

Comment: 1) We're measuring a *relative* change in arm length, i.e. the longer the better, given a certain minimal *absolute* sensitivity.

Comment: 2) the F-Ps are made for 'signal' and 'power' recycling, not for getting 'longer arms' (as explained in comment 1, they don't improve the detection of relative change in arm length). I believe the recycling, both in power and in signal, works because a resonator enhances the light wave only for a certain frequency, within a certain bandwidth. If I choose this bandwidth properly, i.e. 30Hz - 3kHz (= the measurement range of the detector), only signals within this bandwidth will be enhanced. Everything else, i.e. the noise, will not be enhanced. Therefore my overall SNR improves.

Comment: adding to 1): I think they tried passing the interferometer arms twice at GEO600 but in the end the thermal noise from the mirror adds up from every pass and in the end the SNR remains unchanged